# If input(type number) value is over 50 then disable submit button

Tags: javascript, html

For a small homework problem, I need to add a `function` that will detect `onkeyup` event. Then, if `input` value is greater than 50, a button should get disabled! Here's what I have tried:

```
<input id="input_field" onkeyup="myFunction()">
<button id="bttnsubmit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `myFunction()` check if the value inside the box is greater than 50, if it is so then disable the submit button else do nothing.

This is what your final code will look like.

```
function myFunction(){
    var inpNumber = document.getElementById("input_field").value,
           submitButton = document.getElementById("bttnsubmit");
    if(inpNumber > 50){
        submitButton.disabled = true;
    }else{
        submitButton.disabled = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can pass `this` object to the function and check the value inside the function to enable/disable the button:

```js
function myFunction(el){
  if(Number(el.value) > 50)
    document.getElementById('bttnsubmit').disabled = true;
  else
    document.getElementById('bttnsubmit').disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<input id="input_field" onkeyup="myFunction(this)">
<button id="bttnsubmit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

remmember to add jquery link in your Head tag

```
  function myFunction(){
    if(parseInt('#input_field').val() >50){
    $('#bttnsubmit').prop('disabled' ,true) ; 

    }else{
    $('#bttnsubmit').prop('disabled' ,false) ; 
    }

    }
```